# Using "this" in another constructor

Tags: java, constructor, this

Suppose you have a class with this constructor:

```
public SomeObj(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

All good. But now if you want to clone the object, I want a constructor to accept one argument with an object from that type, so inside the constructor all (necessary) fields can be copied.

```
public SomeObj(SomeObj objectToClone) { ... }
```

But now which of the following two ways is better? What are the advantages and disadvantages (performance (byte code), readability...)?

```
// 1
public SomeObj(SomeObj objectToClone) {
    this.x = objectToClone.x;
    this.y = objectToClone.y;
}

// 2
public SomeObj(SomeObj objectToClone) {
    this(objectToClone.x, objectToClone.y);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would go with the latter, personally.

Where possible, I try to make exactly *one* constructor have a "real" body, and make all others delegate to it. That's not always possible - in particular, different constructors may need to delegate to different superconstructors - but it's nice knowing there's *one* place you can put extra initialization, logging, breakpoints etc which will always get hit.

Comment: +1: Having one "real" constructor all the others call means the functionality will be consistent between constructors.  Having different code in different constructors can be a nightmare.

Comment: Although it's just a vision on this subject, I would like to accept this answer (even though you already have loads of points and medals). Because this vision gives me a clear view on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Number 2 is better. Why? because you are no longer repeating yourself, setting a member in two different constructors.

There is no performance hit really, unless the miniscule extra indirection of calling `this()` is going to affect you (and i doubt you can even measure this difference accurately).

Comment: @Mudu: i m not sure if the compiler inlines it, but yea, it might!

Answer (score 2):

If you use the second option, you don't have to change `public SomeObj(SomeObj objectToClone)` every time you change the implementation of `public SomeObj(int x, int y)`. So it is better as it allows you to avoid duplicating code.

Answer (score 1):

The latter does not build anymore as soon as you add another parameter, let's say `z`. If you'd take the first approach, you might just forget to copy `z`. It still builds, but doesn't work properly.

Comment: Don't build but the compiler give you and error, but the first.... builds but it doesn't work if you add another parameter.

Comment: That is what I wanted to point out. I tried to express myself more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not C++. Override .clone() method from Object class for copy objects. It's true way

Comment: +1 for the option. But it does not vote for one of the options. From `clone`, I'd personally invoke the constructor instead of copying the fields again.

Comment: Isn't clone() traditionally used for deep copying? I think it should be overridden in that case only.

Comment: Okay, but the question is not about the clone thing — that was just an example. It's about passing `this(...)` to another constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1
public SomeObj(SomeObj objectToClone) {
    this.x = objectToClone.x;
    this.y = objectToClone.y;
}
```

is better.

Your second option would require you to update your constructor each time you add a new parameter. Also, if you have to call that in 100 places with 100 properties to list in each constructor, it's obvious it starts loosing readability.

I can't understand why you would like to pass multiple properties of the same object as parameter instead of passing the object. There's no reason for that.

Compare these two:

```
public SomeObj(SomeObj objectToClone) {
    this.x = objectToClone.x;
    this.y = objectToClone.y;
    this.z = objectToClone.z;
    this.p = objectToClone.p;
    this.s = objectToClone.s;
    this.a = objectToClone.a;
    this.b = objectToClone.b;
    }
```

and then call `SomeObj(obj)` 10 times in your code.

versus `SomeObj(obj.x,obj.y,obj.z,obj.p,obj.s,obj.t,obj.a,obj.b);` 10 times in your code

Also, with the second option you have no guarantee that the parameters passed are what you want, so you could get something like this: **`SomeObj(obj.x,obj.y,obj2.z,obj3.p,0,0,-1,null);`**